React Application and Spring Boot Application in local host on different port
I have login page in ReactJS(frontend) runs in localhost:3000 and my backend code in which validates the customer in java springboot(backend) localhost:8080 .
I faced the cross origin issues when I do the api call from frontend to backend ,

Will it work after solving the cross origin issue in localhost ?
Is it good Practice to test it in localhost with different ports for development testing ?

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

This is a broad question. Whether it will be solved if you fix it for localhost depends on how you configure it. Since you haven't shared any configuration, we can't go into detail either. Whether it's a good practice depends on whether your production environment will be similar or not, but is in addition an opinionated question to ask.

yes, It Will  work after solving the cross origin issue, just add cores config class in you springboot.
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
@Configuration
public class CorsConfigReact{
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 
UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
}

